# Numpy is already installed，but “ImportError：the module named ‘numpy’ is not found” is still provoked

Tags: module, pypy

I try to create a "pypy3.7" environment by Anaconda,but get a problems as follows:

“numpy is already in the list”

[image: 1]

“importError” still happens

[image: 2]

I have tried reinstalled several times but nothing different happens.

Comment: How did you create your pypy environment? Did you follow the [directions in the blog post](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html)? When you say "Anaconda" that makes me thing you are not using the conda-forge channel (either set it as a default or always use `-c conda-forge` in your commands

Comment: Thx for your reply，I solved this problem by using conda rather than pip to reinstall the ‘numpy’ . And I found conda install  'numpy-1.19.5' instead of  'numpy-1.21.6'  by pip.